# Exception org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet while feching data using hql

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I am trying to get bill details using following query

```
String hql =  "from BillDetails as bd "
               + "left join fetch bd.billPaidDetails  as bpd"
               + "where bd.client.id=:cid "
               + "and sum(bpd.amount)<bd.total "
               + "order by bd.addDate";

Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
query.setParameter("cid", cid);
obj = query.list();
```

Here one bill have many `billPaidDetails` I want to fetch only those bills that are not fully paid for that I am using `sum(bpd.amount)<bd.total` in where condition but this is showing
`Exception org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet`
How to resolve above exception?

Comment: Please show us the *whole* stacktrace.

Comment: Please show us by running the raw query.

Answer (score 0):

update to `List<BillDetails> obj = query.list();`.if it can not resolve your problem.I want you show us by the all exception and related entities.